# php count occurence in an array and getting average

Tags: php, arrays

I'm totally not good with arrays and I have a database query that return this:

```
 ID USER    TASK    Points  Time
1   admin   Accounting  1   -7
1   admin   Accounting  1   -15
1   admin   Accounting  1   -1146
1   admin   Accounting  1   -2
1   admin   Accounting  1   -3
2   Mike    Encoding    1   -7
2   Mike    Encoding    1   -55
2   Mike    Encoding    1   0
2   Mike    Encoding    1   -6
3   Adam    Printing    1   -5
3   Adam    Printing    1   -12
3   Adam    Printing    1   -7
3   Adam    Printing    1   -4
3   Adam    Printing    1   -8
3   Adam    Printing    1   -10
```

I've use a loop to count how many points each user have but I got a problem getting their average time which is (sum of time / count(time))

SO far my code is this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

            $countCase[$row['TASK']] = isset($countCase[$row['TASK']]) ? $countCase[$row['TASK']] + 1 : 1;  

            $countUser[$row['TASK']][$row['USER']] = isset($countUser[$row['TASK']][$row['USER']]) ? $countUser[$row['TASK']][$row['USER']] + 1 : 1;                    
        }
```

it basically count all the occurences but having difficulty getting the average time also is this array good for inserting it into a database or better suggestion?

Comment: Or you can use a query that take advantage of mysql `SUM()`, `COUNT()`  and `GROUP BY`

Comment: I'll try to do that , Thanks!

Comment: I guess `(SUM(Time)/COUNT(ID)) AS TimeAverage` with `GROUP BY USER` will work. Or with `GROUP BY USER, TASK` or `GROUP BY TASK, USER`. Whichever suits your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your query using group and MySQL functions to solve this question.